# Return a String from a JButton press Action Listener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, output

I've been trying for a while to get a JButton I have to return a string and I have it working to an extent however it only works when i'm using the System.out.println() method.

**My Relevant Code:**

```
private String answer;

public void inputDataButton(JButton inButton)
{
inButton.addActionListener(new Action1());
}

public String returnAnswer()
{
return answer;
}

private void fileAnswer(String inString)
{
answer = new String(inString);
}

public class Action1 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String sub = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input The Date");
        fileAnswer(sub);
    }
}
```

**With my Main controlling it:**

```
public class test
{
    protected static JTextField text;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    javaUI base = new javaUI("Date Killer", 800, 800);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Place Holder");
    base.addLabel(label, 1, 0, false);

    JButton button = new JButton("Press Here");
    base.addButton(button, 0, 0, false);

    String str = "EMPTY";

    base.inputDataButton(button);

    while (str == "EMPTY")
        {
        str = base.returnAnswer();
        }

    System.out.println(str + " TEST");
    label.setText(str + "SETTED");
    }
}
```

JavaUI is simply another class with simplifies the entire JFrame and Jpanel setup for Labels, Buttons etc.

Anyways, heres my problem. In the main class, in the while statement, str is successfully set to the string *if I have a System.out.println() statement directly after.*
This obviously makes quite a mess of the terminal as it repeates "EMPTY" 100+ times until the button is pressed.

However if I remove that statement, nothing is obviously printed out, but str is never set to the str either.

I've been messing around with this for quite a while (New to all java UI stuff, mainly just worked in the calculations part of things) and I've yet to find a working solution that doesn't make a mess of my terminal. Thanks for all the Help!!!

Cail

Comment: What is the `System.out.println()` statement that makes it work? And, why is `base.returnAnswer()` in a `while` loop? Does it return different answers every time it is called?

Comment: Since I dont know what point the button is going to be pressed, I've set a while loop for the string that keeps circulating until the string isn't "EMPTY". However it only exits the loop if there a System.out.println(str) statement inside the loop, otherwise it becomes endless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's a little strange to use a loop to "wait" for the action to happen. You can watch your cpu usage and it could be dead if it loops forever.

2) Also, the method will return no matter whether your button is clicked -- Before the action happens, the method returns a `null` string according to your code. And in your main method, `str == "EMPTY"` soon becomes false after the first round. Then you'll see "null TEST" on your screen.

---

Try to put the code after `while` loop into `actionPerformed` method or `fileAnswer` method and delete the loop:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String sub = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input The Date");
    System.out.println(sub + " TEST");
    label.setText(sub + "SETTED");
}
```

Also, I am not sure why you call `answer = new String(inString)`. If you want to assign it to another variable, you only need to call `answer = inString` since String is unmodifiable. And in this case, you don't to do this.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the answer = new String(inString) part, in my most recent code I changed that. I could do that except what I really want to do is feed it to main and put the inputted string into str as I'm planning to use it for further calculations, the label isn't a necessity, only for the visual aspect for the finished program, what i'm trying to do is get the button press to return the inputted string into the String str in main. Thanks for the help though! :)

Comment: @CailDemetri You're welcome. The point is whatever calculation you try to do after the button is pressed, you should call it in `actionPerformed()` method as I showed. I just took the example in your question. You need to change the design anyway. Or could you show the original requirements and I could help you to work out a more proper way to do the job.

Comment: ahhh, I see what you mean, I might try creating a static class for the calculations. As for what I'm trying to do, Is create a sort of calendar program, except its for someone else so I cant do any of the input through the command prompt. So I'm trying to get the user to input a date through the input dialog press created from pressing a button, that grab that inputted string and perform calculations on it.The problem being that I cant figure out how to return said string into my main. I might try it with another class but i'd much rather do it in the main. Thanks for clearing that up :D